# Cannot get rspec to test both parts of an if else puppet statement

Tags: ruby, rspec, puppet

I am writing unit tests for our puppet code (puppet 3.8). I have a variable set by data in hiera. For example, I have this code in puppet:

```
# globals value coming from hiera
$status = $globals['yum']['status']
if $status =~ /on/ {
  service { 'yum-cron':
    ensure     => 'running',
    enable     => true,
    hasrestart => true,
    require    => [ Package['yum-cron'], File['/var/lock/subsys/'] ]
  }
} else {
  service { 'yum-cron':
    ensure     => 'stopped',
    enable     => false,
    hasrestart => true,
    require    => Package['yum-cron'],
  }
  file {'/var/lock/subsys/yum-cron':
    ensure  => 'absent',
    require => Package['yum-cron'],
  }
}
```

In my rspec test file, I have the following code to test both the parts of the `if`/`else`:

```
context 'If the globals yum status = on' do
  it 'The service resource yum-cron should exist' do
    is_expected.to contain_service('yum-cron').with(
      ensure: 'running',
      enable:  true,
      hasrestart: true,
      require: ['Package[yum-cron]', 'File[/var/lock/subsys/]' ]
    )
  end
end

context 'If the globals yum status = off' do
  let(:status) {'off'}
  it 'The service resource yum-cron should NOT exist' do
    is_expected.to contain_service('yum-cron').with(
      ensure: 'stopped',
      enable:  false,
      hasrestart: true,
      require: 'Package[yum-cron]'
    )
  end
end
```

No matter what I do in my `xxx_setup.rb` file to test both parts of the `if`/`else` statement, only the part that matches the value coming from hiera tests successfully. Because the value from hiera sets the value of `$status` to `"on"`, that section evaluates successfully in the rspec test code. But the section where I try to test for the value of `$status` to be `"off"` fails no matter how I try to set the value of the status variable in rspec. When the puppet catalog is generated, it seems to generate only the section that matches what is in hiera and not what I set the `$status` variable to in rspec.

What am I missing?

Comment: @supremebeing7's answer is on the right track, and to answer this properly I would need to see exactly how $globals is really being set.

Answer (score 2):

`let(:status)` in your rspec code is just setting a local variable `status`, it is not setting the global `$status`. What's more, your puppet code is setting that `$status` global at the top of the file, so even if you could set it in your rspec code, it would be overwritten.

You say `$globals` is getting it's values from hiera. I've never used that before, but if you're using `rspec-puppet` gem, it looks like you can [define the path to your hiera yaml file](https://github.com/rodjek/rspec-puppet#hiera-integration). So you could then possibly overwrite the value after that, or have separate hiera yaml files for each test.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @supremebeing7 for setting me on the right path.  I created a second hiera yaml file which contained alternate values for which I wanted to test in my rspec code.  I added the following code to the section in my rspec file where I needed to test with the alternate value:

```
context 'If the globals yum status = off' do
  let(:hiera_config) { 
    'spec/fixtures/alt_hiera/hiera.yaml' }
    hiera = Hiera.new({ :config => 
    'spec/fixtures/alt_hiera/hiera.yaml' })
    globals = hiera.lookup('globals', nil, nil)
```

This alternate hiera file had the value of "off" set for $globals['yum']['status'] and my test passed.